# What alternatives do we have for Smalidea to debug smali code on Android?

Tags: android, debugging, smali

I'm trying to debug some low level smali code on Android Studio and the alternative I found is this [plugin](https://github.com/JesusFreke/smalidea) for Android Studio but some things in it doesn't work very well, for example:

- In the middle of debugging, if I press F9 so it continues until the next breakpoint it actually never stops on it, just passes by and even lost references it had leaving the application on the host waiting for the debugger
- If I press F8 on a line of code with a function call in which inside this function there is another breakpoint it also never stop on it and end up with the same situation as before

Anyway I found this solution around 2018 when I was doing some research and I guess we might have better options (maybe built in android studio? or maybe using another IDE?). So my question is how to debug smali code properly in ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Some Android decompilers like Jadx-GUI have a built-in Smali debugger.

Comment: Jadx-GUI doesn't work well too, but you can try.